# need to send order details once order is created using SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I need to send order details once order is created using SOAP API,

Now i am storing all the orders that are creating in the gap of 5 mins in a link and making the link refresh every minute using cron job and passing the values to external application , is this the right approach

How to send order details instantly once order is created

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sales_order_place_after event to get the order data. This event is dispatched in Mage_Sales_Model_Order::place()

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_place_after', array('order'=>$this));
```

The observer method should look like this:

```
public function placeOrderAfter($observer){
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    //your code
}
```

Next, you can do whatever you like with the order data (create cron tasks, send data to the external application, etc).